# Default scope for production but not in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord, default-scope

I have a model which I want to limit the results to those of a particular client so client number 1 (my database contains other client data too)

so I have a scope like this:

```
default_scope {
  where(
    :owner_id => 1,
    :someother_criteria => false
  )
}
```

I want this scope (the :owner_id => 1 part) to be active on production but not in development as I don't have that data and want to test the ui using the data i have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  # define your scope
end
```

or, if you want to define different scopes on different environments, you can do something like this:

```
default_scope do
  case Rails.env
  when 'production'
    # define production default scope
  when 'development'
    # define development default scope
  end
end
```

Comment: that's something i was thinking, but then if i had other search terms that i wanted to keep that it would be duplicate code.

Comment: @JosephLeBrech you can define scopes you want to keep outside that if block right? how are you duplicating code?

Comment: i want them to be default scopes too.

Comment: @JosephLeBrech so you want to define different default scopes? I updated my answer to reflect it.

Comment: this is probably the simplest way to do this. i was thinking you could do `(where(:a=>1) if Rails.env.production?).where(:b=>'b')` but nicer looking.